# Aligning parentheses

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&=\sum_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}\sum_{\substack{y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2=a\\ y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2=b}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_2)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_2)\sum_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1) \sum_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_3\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)\\
&=\sum \limits_{x_2,y_2\in \mathcal{E}} \underbrace{\left(\sum\limits_{\theta_1,a}\sum \limits_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1)\mathds{1}_{\{a\}}(y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2)\right)}_{\mathrm{I}}\\
    &\underbrace{\left(\sum\limits_{\theta_2,b}\sum \limits_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_2\neq x_3}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)\mathds{1}_{\{b\}}(y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2)\right)}_{\mathrm{II}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The above code represents the following formula [image]

Question: how to move the last line to right so that it should be on the same level as the above parenthesis?

Comment: More important than the align here is to insert a `+` or a `\times` to make it clear what is going on (mathematically).

Comment: @mickep, oh I see what you meant. There should be a product between two parenthesis.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you use an "inner" `aligned` environment to align the two `\underbrace` items. I would also use `\smashoperator[r]{...}` wrappers to "snug up" the summation symbols and the items they add up, and I would give the `\mathds{1}...` items -- they are indicator functions or operators, right? --`\mathop` (math operator) status. I would also use `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` instead of `\left` and `\right` to size the large parentheses.

Incidentally, shouldn't you be using three pairs of large parentheses in the first row of the multi-row expression, to group the three summation expressions?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\newcommand\oneE[1][\mathcal{E}]{\mathop{\mathds{1}^{}_{#1}}} % indicator functions

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&=\sum_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}\,
  \smashoperator[r]{%
  \sum_{\substack{y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2=a\\ y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2=b}}}
  \oneE(x_2)\oneE(y_2)
  \smashoperator[r]{%
  \sum_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}}
  \oneE(x_1)\oneE(y_1) 
  \smashoperator[r]{%
  \sum_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_3\neq x_2}}}
  \oneE(x_3)\oneE(y_3) \\[\jot]
&=\sum _{x_2,y_2\in \mathcal{E}}
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  &\underbrace{\Biggl(\,
  \sum_{\theta_1,a}\,
  \smashoperator[r]{%
  \sum _{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}}
  \oneE(x_1)\oneE(y_1)\oneE[\{a\}](y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2)
  \!\Biggr)}_{\mathrm{I}} \times \\
  &\underbrace{\Biggl(\,
  \sum_{\theta_2,b}\,
  \smashoperator[r]{%
  \sum _{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_2\neq x_3}}}
  \oneE(x_3)\oneE(y_3)\oneE[\{b\}](y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2)
  \!\Biggr)}_{\mathrm{II}} 
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's an augmented solution. Compared with the solution given above, the new solution also (a) encloses the three summation terms in row 1 in their own pairs of large parentheses and (b) takes care to place the first row of any material below the `\sum` terms at the same height, irrespective of the presence of `\substack` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro
\usepackage{dsfont}    % for \mathds macro
\newcommand\oneE[1][\mathcal{E}]{\mathop{\mathds{1}^{}_{\!#1}}} % indicator function
\newcommand\mystrut{\vphantom{\sqrt{r}}} % set up a typographic strut 

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{\mathclap{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\mystrut\\a,b}}}
  \Biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{%
     \sum_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}}
     \oneE(x_1)\oneE(y_1)\!\Biggr)\!
  \Biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{%
     \sum_{\substack{y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2=a\\ y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2=b}}}
     \oneE(x_2)\oneE(y_2)\!\Biggr)\!
  \Biggl(\,\smashoperator[r]{%
     \sum_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_3\neq x_2}}}
     \oneE(x_3)\oneE(y_3)\!\Biggr) \\[\jot]
&\qquad=
 \sum _{x_2,y_2\in \mathcal{E}\mystrut}
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  &\underbrace{\Biggl(\,
     \sum_{\theta_1,a\mystrut}\,
     \smashoperator[r]{%
     \sum_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}}
     \oneE(x_1)\oneE(y_1)\oneE[\{a\}](y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2)
     \!\Biggr)}_{\mathrm{I}}  \times \\
  &\underbrace{\Biggl(\,
     \sum_{\theta_2,b\mystrut}\,
     \smashoperator[r]{%
     \sum_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_2\neq x_3}}}
     \oneE(x_3)\oneE(y_3)\oneE[\{b\}](y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2)
     \!\Biggr)}_{\mathrm{II}} 
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As an opinion, I don't think the brackets on the first line contribute at all to clarity, and they look awful.

Comment: @MartinArgerami - Speaking for myself, I'd say that the longish terms below the summation symbols, such as `y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a`, are the prime culprits in the typographical crime that's unfolding before our eyes...

Answer (score 5):

I placed the two groupings in a top-aligned `aligned` environment.  I also had to `\rlap` the period punctuation, to not misalign things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&=\sum_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}
\sum_{\substack{y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2=a\\ 
y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2=b}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_2)
\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_2)\sum_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}
\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)
\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1) \sum_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}
\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_3\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)
\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)\\
&=\sum \limits_{x_2,y_2\in \mathcal{E}} 
\begin{aligned}[t]
\underbrace{\left(\sum\limits_{\theta_1,a}\sum 
\limits_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}
\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1)
\mathds{1}_{\{a\}}(y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2)\right)}_{\mathrm{I}}\\
    \times \underbrace{\left(\sum\limits_{\theta_2,b}\sum 
\limits_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_2\neq x_3}}
\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)
\mathds{1}_{\{b\}}(y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2)\right)}_{\mathrm{II}}
\rlap{.}
\end{aligned}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

By adding the `nccmath` package and use `alignat*` math environment. For make the first equation narrower is used `\smashoperator[r]{...}` similarly as @Mico in his answer (+1).

**Edit:** As suggested @Mico, `\smashoperator[r]{...}` is now used in the second and third row of equations too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath,
            mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\begin{alignat*}{2}
& = \mathrlap{%
    \sum_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}\ 
    \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\substack{y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2=a\\
                  y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2=b}}}
        \mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_2)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_2)
    \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\
                   x_1\neq x_2}}}
        \mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1)
    \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_3\neq x_2}}}
        \mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)  
            }
    &&   \\
%
& = \sum\limits_{x_2,y_2\in \mathcal{E}}\ 
    &&   \underbrace{\left(\sum\limits_{\theta_1,a}\
         \smashoperator[r]{\sum\limits_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ 
                                                  x_1\neq x_2}}}
        \mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1)
        \mathds{1}_{\{a\}}(y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2)\right)}_{\mathrm{I}} \times\\
%
&   &&   \underbrace{\left(\sum\limits_{\theta_2,b}\ 
         \smashoperator[r]{\sum \limits_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_2\neq x_3}}}
        \mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)
        \mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)\mathds{1}_{\{b\}}(y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2)\right)}_{\mathrm{II}}.
    \end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows text area borders)

Comment: @Mico, you are right. Using them in other rows improve equation looks. Thank you for pointing me to this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty way to do it using `\hphantom`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&=\sum_{\substack{\theta_1,\theta_2\\a,b}}\sum_{\substack{y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2=a\\ y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2=b}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_2)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_2)\sum_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1) \sum_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_3\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)\\
&=\sum \limits_{x_2,y_2\in \mathcal{E}} \underbrace{\left(\sum\limits_{\theta_1,a}\sum \limits_{\substack{y_1-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_1=a\\ x_1\neq x_2}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_1)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_1)\mathds{1}_{\{a\}}(y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_1x_2)\right)}_{\mathrm{I}}\\
&\hphantom{{}=\sum \limits_{x_2,y_2\in \mathcal{E}}}\underbrace{\left(\sum\limits_{\theta_2,b}\sum \limits_{\substack{y_3-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_3=b\\ x_2\neq x_3}}\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(x_3)\mathds{1}_{\mathcal{E}}(y_3)\mathds{1}_{\{b\}}(y_2-\sqrt{r}\theta_2x_2)\right)}_{\mathrm{II}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of rendered version of the MWE]

Be aware of the `{}` before the `=` in the `\hphantom`, if you omit it, the `=` will probably not be considered a binary math operator resulting in slightly different spacing.

If you want the multiplication sign, you can add it to the end of the second to last line, or add it to the beginning of the first line using eg. `\mathllap`